# Python Return case insensitive string from a list, if it contains case insensitive substring

Tags: python, string, list, substring

How can I return case insensitive **string** from a **list**, if it contains case insensitive **substring**? The returned string should be **case insensitive**

I was able to return string from the list, but I'm using the lowercase method. I would like to return it to its original state without modifying

```
entriesList = ['CSS', 'Django', 'Git', 'HTML', 'Python']

substring = "g"

def substringSearch(substring, entriesList):
  return [string for string in (string.casefold() for string in entriesList) if substring in string] 


print(substringSearch(substring, entriesList))
```

Result:

```
['django', 'git']
```

What I would like to get:

```
['Django', 'Git']
```

Comment: Your part of the comprehension in the parenthesis changes the string you're placing in your final list.  Just casefold in your conditional at the end of the comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `lower()` or `casefold()` in the test in comprehension.

```
[string for string in entriesList if substring in string.casefold()]
```

You don't need to make a new generator for this. That will give you:

```
entriesList = ['CSS', 'Django', 'Git', 'HTML', 'Python']

substring = "g"

def substringSearch(substring, entriesList):
      return [string for string in entriesList if substring in string.casefold()] 


print(substringSearch(substring, entriesList))

# ['Django', 'Git']
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem perfectly